# Reclassifying Raster Value Classes based on pre-defined function using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, reclassify

I have this distance raster (shown in the image below).

Is it possible to reclassify the distance values based on the description below-

For distance values 0-100 (new value decreases linearly from 10 to 1);
For distance values 100-200 (new value=1);
For distance values 200-500 (new value increases linearly from 1 to 10);
For distance >500 (new value=10)

The graph below shows the function.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation to linearly scale 100-0 to 1-10 is:

```
-0.09x + 10
```

The equation to linearly scale 200-500 to 1-10 is:

```
0.03x - 5
```

You could use nested [`Con` functions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) in the raster calculator to apply these equations:

```
Con("distance" <= 100, 
    -0.09 * "distance" + 10,
    Con("distance" < 200,
        1,
        Con("distance" <= 500,
            0.03 * "distance" - 5,
            10
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try it on the data.

Comment: It works! thank you again @user2856

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to above, you can reclassify your distance into 4 classes and type this in calculator:

```
Pick("Reclass",[-0.09,0,0.03,0]) * "Distance"+Pick("Reclass",[10,1,-5,10])
```

[image]